# The app reference non-public selectors: _updateDelegateFlags, number, setNumber:, tableExists:

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8

I am getting this error while uploading my build to app store, my app is currently on app store. But after changing some sdks ( google analytics and flurry ) and some iOS8 changes, i am getting this error. I haven't used any non-public function.[image: Screen Shot of error]

Please help me..

Thanks..